# Symfony2 Установка

Tags: php

При конфигурировании Symfony2 возникает ошибка "Upgrade your PCRE extension (8.0+)". Как наиболее безболезненно обновить PCRE?

Пробовал по [этой инструкции](http://www.linuxrsp.ru/artic/pcre3.html) , не помогает.

Comment: С помощью вашего пакетного менеджера.